# Expression for the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 +\|x\|^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm having troubles with the Fourier transform of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 +\|x\|^2} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. For the case $n=1$ I got $\hat{f}(\xi) = \pi e^{-2\pi |\xi|}$ using residues. Does the general case have a nice expression? How is that expression obtained?

Comment: Take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472469/help-with-fourier-transform-integral?lq=1

Comment: And here as well http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97784/integral-in-n%E2%88%92dimensional-euclidean-space

Comment: And the answer is probably here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662056/integral-in-n-dimensional-euclidean-space

Answer (score 3):

It's not in $L^2$ for $n \ge 4$. For $n \le 3$, assume wlog $\xi$ is  in the direction of one of the coordinate axes.